# Cryptographic algorithm violation in vera code report

Tags: java, md5, veracode

Using DisgestUils.md5Hex to generate 32 digits random number in java.  It's being captured as Violation in veracode report.

Could you please advise how do I generate 32 digits number in java which should not capture in veracode report.

Comment: Using a hashing algorithm like "MD5" has nothing to do with "random number". Second: as a (bad) replace you could use SHA-256 as hashing algorithm and truncate the output to the desired length.

Answer (score 2):

While I can't speak for Veracode, you probably want to use an instance of [SecureRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/SecureRandom.html) to create random numbers for cryptographic or security token purposes.

To get thirty two hexadecimal characters out of SecureRandom you need sixteen bytes and can then use a StringBuilder to turn those bytes into a String cheaply.

For example:

```java
import java.security.SecureRandom;

...

SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
random.nextBytes(bytes);

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (byte b : bytes) {
  String hex = Integer.toHexString(b & 0xff);
  if (hex.length() == 1) {
    builder.append('0');
  }
  builder.append(hex);
}

String token = builder.toString();
```